# JMeter - SubResults are not displaying in Summary table etc

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

JMeter 5.4.1.
JSR223 script contains several sub steps in complex transaction.

The sub step contains a code like that:

```
// SendMessage:

def myResult_SendMessage = new org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult()
myResult_SendMessage.setSampleLabel('SendMessage')
myResult_SendMessage.sampleStart()

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Send a message')]")));
WebElement Depot_SendMessage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Send a message')]")); 
Depot_SendMessage.click(); 

myResult_SendMessage.setResponseCodeOK()
myResult_SendMessage.setSuccessful(true)
myResult_SendMessage.sampleEnd()
myResult_SendMessage.latencyEnd()
myResult_SendMessage.setResponseData(driver.getPageSource());
SampleResult.addSubResult(myResult_SendMessage,false)
```

I want to see all sub results, not only the main result, in "Summary table" / "Aggregate report" / "Synthesis report".

Actually, I see subresults only in "View Results Tree", but not in "Summary table".

In user.property file:
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true

in Summary table - configuration - "save sub results" are checked also,

but sub results are not displaying as a labels in resulting tables.

What should I do to collect sub results displayed in Summary table using defined setSampleLabel?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the following lines to  *user.properties* file:

```
webdriver.sampleresult_class=com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.SampleResultWithSubs
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up

More information:

- [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you!
This hint saves sub results to csv and then sub results could be read from csv. However, I still don't see sub results after test in tables. Is it expected behavior?

Comment: I don't know in which "tables" do you "expect" to see the sub-results

Comment: In "Summary table" / "Aggregate report" / "Synthesis report".